# C# Merging Two or more Text Files side by side

Tags: c#, performance, merge

```
using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(FinishedFile))
{
    int lineNum = 0;
    while (lineNum < FilesLineCount.Min())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= FilesToMerge.Count() - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i != FilesToMerge.Count() - 1)
            {
                var CurrentFile = File.ReadLines(FilesToMerge[i]).Skip(lineNum).Take(1);
                string CurrentLine = string.Join("", CurrentFile);
                writer.Write(CurrentLine + ",");
            }
            else
            {
                var CurrentFile = File.ReadLines(FilesToMerge[i]).Skip(lineNum).Take(1);
                string CurrentLine = string.Join("", CurrentFile);
                writer.Write(CurrentLine + "\n");
            }
        }
        lineNum++;
    }
}
```

The current way i am doing this is just too slow. I am merging files that are each 50k+ lines long with various amounts of data.

for ex:
File 1
1
2
3
4

File 2
4
3
2
1

i need this to merge into being a third file
File 3
1,4
2,3
3,2
4,1
P.S. The user can pick as many files as they want from any locations.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your code and your problem statement dont seem to match like I would expect.  Do you have _exactly_ two files (File1 & File2) and you are trying to add the combination of each file to a new file (File3)?  The combination logic (in psuedocode) being: `file3[i] = file1[i] + "," + file2[i]`

Comment: In each iteration you're reading the whole files again, you should read them line by line in each iteration

Comment: @maccettura this is any amount of files and they all go to file 3, i added that at the end, maybe my logic is the issue any help is appreciated. The current code i have merges them correctly it is just extremely slow for the file sizes i use.

Comment: Are your files the same length/ number of lines?

Comment: @AdamStrobel I see what you wrote at the end but it still does not make sense.  Is the user able to pick the path of any _two_ files?  Or are they allowed to pick the path of an _unlimited_ amount of files?

Comment: @pijemcolu no, the merge completes at the lowest line count, For example if one file is 30 lines the other is 40, then only 30 would merge together. That is what my while loop is for.

Comment: @maccettura yes they browse to every file that they need to merge to the ending file(File 3). Hopefully this clears up the confusion i am generally new and i know my code might be confusing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You approach is slow because of the `Skip` and `Take` in the loops.

You could use a dictionary to collect all line-index' lines:

```
string[] allFileLocationsToMerge = { "filepath1", "filepath2", "..." };
var mergedLists = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
foreach (string file in allFileLocationsToMerge)
{
    string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
    for (int lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < allLines.Length; lineIndex++)
    {
        bool indexKnown = mergedLists.TryGetValue(lineIndex, out List<string> allLinesAtIndex);
        if (!indexKnown)
            allLinesAtIndex = new List<string>();
        allLinesAtIndex.Add(allLines[lineIndex]);
        mergedLists[lineIndex] = allLinesAtIndex;
    }
}

IEnumerable<string> mergeLines = mergedLists.Values.Select(list => string.Join(",", list));
File.WriteAllLines("targetPath", mergeLines);
```

Comment: Thank you this was much faster and i did not know the skip and take makes it so much slower. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach - this implementation only stores in memory one set of lines from each file simultaneously, thus reducing memory pressure significantly (if that is an issue).

```
public static void MergeFiles(string output, params string[] inputs)
{
    var files = inputs.Select(File.ReadLines).Select(iter => iter.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();
    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
    bool any;

    using (var outFile = File.CreateText(output))
    {
        do
        {
            line.Clear();
            any = false;

            foreach (var iter in files)
            {
                if (!iter.MoveNext())
                    continue;

                if (line.Length != 0)
                    line.Append(", ");

                line.Append(iter.Current);
                any = true;
            }

            if (any)
                outFile.WriteLine(line.ToString());
        }
        while (any);
    }

    foreach (var iter in files)
    {
        iter.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This also handles files of different lengths.