# How to merge .txt files in c#?

Tags: c#, file, text, merge

I want to make it so in c# it will take two text files and merge them together to "output.txt" like shown below. Will be very happy if someone could help me.

file1.txt:
*hello*
file2.txt:
*test*
output.txt:
*hello test*

Comment: Publish the code you tried so far and in what part you're having trouble

Comment: What is your merge rule? Line by line? What if duplicated? What if conflicted? Provide code and more information bro

Comment: I need to merge them line by line so that line 1 in the first file is the same as line1 in the second file. and so on. I didn't have a clue on how to code this so i don't really have a code yet...

Comment: @MaBoiii so [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585712/c-sharp-merging-two-or-more-text-files-side-by-side) could answer you yet?

Comment: I have solved this